# Using a regex to "undo" quoted strings

Tags: regex, postgresql

My regex knowledge is failing me here. The problem is, given a string such as:

```
this "is a string" of ' characters that' i want to process -really
```

... I need to turn it into:

```
this & (is <-> a <-> string) & of & (characters <-> that) & i & want & to & process & !really
```

(The specific problem here is turning a user-friendly input into a PostgreSQL `tsquery` with more advanced features than the function `plain_tsquery` allows.)

(note the extra space in front of *characters* above.)

Is this even doable with a regex, or do I need to just buckle down and write code that parses the input directly?

Comment: Do you need to do the whole transformation in the PostgreSQL side? It would be easier to transform the input on the SQL client side.

Comment: What you want to do is possible with some regex engines but not PostgreSQL one.

Comment: This is going to be done on the client side, not the PostgreSQL side, so we're not limited to the PostgreSQL regex engine.

Comment: Well, I made [an attempt](https://regex101.com/r/062sZr/6) at getting some of these elements into regex. I gotta sleep now, but maybe someone else can do the substitution part of this? I can't figure out how to do conditionals in a substitution. Honestly, regex is the wrong tool for this job,

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do what I needed just using shlex and a bit code, although if anyone would like to take a stab at it, I'm always excited to see more regex fun!